# Loading a project from a virtual machine into Eclipse

Tags: virtualization, svn, windows-vista, freebsd, eclipse

Here is the setup -  I have a server with the svn repositories containing projects. I have a virtual machine on my Vista computer running FreeBSD acting as a server to test projects locally. Projects are checkedout/committed/updated from the virtual machine.

I wish to be able to modify the checked out project on my Vista machine using Eclipse. Am I able to load the file system from the virtual machine? Here a subversion plugin is not useful as the virtual machine will be doing the committing to the main server.

Any possible solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's considered a bad idea to share a working copy between different platforms, and I have run into problems with it. So I would advise against using Samba to access your working copy.

It's perfectly valid to have multiple working copies of the same repository, so the best solution would be to host your svn repositories on a single machine (like your current windows pc), by running a server to share them, for example [svnserve](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html) (since Apache would be overkill).

The svn client in your VM can then checkout and commit to the svnserve server on the Windows host. The Eclipse client on your Windows host (with Subversive or Subclipse plugin) can also checkout and commit from the svnserve on localhost. Just run a simple Update before you start working on a different machine.

If you simple think of those two machines (the Windows host, and the VM) as two separate developers working on the same project it will make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could install Samba on the virtual machine for network access from the Vista side.

If you use vmware to host the virtual machine, there is something called shared folders. That might also work.

The cleanest solution of course would be to use svn from both sides.

Comment: Thanks, Ill have a look at Samba and shared folders within VMWare.

By the svn solution, do you mean setting up subversion on the virtual machine aswell. Once modifications are made to the code on Vista, update it to the vm using Tortoise or so. Once that is done I commit from the vitual machine to the server? Wouldnt there be problem updating to the vm then to the server as they will effectively be different repositories?

Thanks again for the advice.

Comment: I haven't thought about svn that way, but that would probably work. My thoughts were to commit the changes either in Vista or on the vm and update on the other side from svn to get the changes.